# Yii2, send AJAX request with link

Tags: ajax, yii2

I need to send AJAX request using link.

```
<a href="#" class="messages_close">
    <i class="far fa-window-close"></i>
</a>
```

May be construction like this?

```
<?php
$js = <<<JS
$(".messages_close").click(function () {
    var id = 8;
    $.ajax({
        url: "'.\yii\helpers\Url::toRoute(['messages/exclude','id'=>8]).'",
        type: "get",
        data: "id="+this.id,
        success: function(){
            alert('SUCCESS');
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('ERROR :: ' +  'id=' + this.id);
        }
    });
});
JS;

$this->registerJs($js);
```

Is it possible? Thank you

### UPDATE 1

Thanks for @vvpanchev and @Serghei Leonenco
I did some changes:

- added use yii\helpers\Url and changed `url:`;
- removed `data: "id="+this.id`
- removed `var id = 8` it used in URL

**I still get ERROR alert! ((**
**How can I get SUCCESS, or better return message from controller?**

Here is my code looks like:

view\messages.php

```
<?php 
use yii\helpers\Url;
?>
...
<a href="#" class="messages_close">
    <i class="far fa-window-close"></i>
</a>
...
<?php
$js = <<<JS
$(".messages_close").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "' . Url::toRoute(['messages/exclude','id'=>8]) . '",
        type: "get",
        success: function(){
            alert('SUCCESS');
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('ERROR');
        }
    });
});
JS;

$this->registerJs($js);
```

MessageController.php (it opens in browser without problem)

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use app\models\MessagesUsers;
use yii\web\Controller;


class MessagesController extends Controller
{
    public function actionExclude($id)
    {
        return 'Success ID=' . $id;
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help!

### SOLUTION

```
<?php
$url = Url::toRoute(['messages/exclude']);
$js = <<<JS
$(".messages_close").on('click', function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "{$url}",
        data: {id: 8},
        type: "get",
        success: function(){
            alert('SUCCESS');
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('ERROR');
        }
    });
});
JS;

$this->registerJs($js);
```

Comment: Why not? What's the problem in your example?

Comment: I got this:
ERROR :: id=undefined

Comment: yes, you have not `this.id`, I think you don't need data in your ajax, because you have `id` in url location. :) or just call in js `id` not `this.id`

Comment: Your error tells you that this dom element that triggered this event , click ,does not have id specified. Use just id as a var element without this.

Comment: Also, like @vvpanchev mentioned you do not need to use `data` attridute, since you have method as `GET` and you already embed this id to the url.

Comment: You can't use concatenation inside of heredoc block (`<<<JS`). Just open HTML source of your page and look how registered script looks like.

Comment: `<script>jQuery(function ($) {
$(".messages_close").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "' . Url::toRoute(['messages/exclude','id'=>8]) . '",
        type: "get",
        success: function(){
            alert('SUCCESS');
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('ERROR');
        }
    });
});
jQuery('#filter-form').yiiActiveForm([], []);
});</script>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$url = Url::toRoute(['messages/exclude']);
$js = <<<JS
$(".messages_close").on('click', function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "{$url}",
        data: {id: 8},
        type: "get",
        success: function(){
            alert('SUCCESS');
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('ERROR');
        }
    });
});
JS;

$this->registerJs($js);
```